# How to hook PMD + Clover in Hudson build using maven?

Tags: hudson, maven-3, clearcase, pmd, clover

we have newly set-up up a Hudson (yes.. Hudson, not Jenkins) CI. The job scheduled in Hudson does the following

a. Connects to IBM ClearCase repository to download the latest source code   
 
  b. Compiles all java source code and Creates a WAR file (by running the project's pom.xml)   
 
  c. Deploys it to a Tomcat6 server

Now, i want to take it one more step further in-terms of bringing in automatic 'Static Code Analyzers' in this process.

I installed PMD/Clover/JavaNCSS plugins in my Hudson instance, but while looking at it's setting, it looks like, these plugins will not perform the static code analyzing. Instead they will just depend upon the reports generated by Maven-PMD/Clover/JavaNCSS plugins and then display them.

But, i was aiming to create the set-up in such a way to **Fail the Build** if the PMD/Clover/JavaNCSS checks result in violations beyond a threshold limit.

Could anyone let me know how to proceed futher ?

**Note**: If this works fine, next i would like to stop developers from checking-in their code into ClearCase in-case of any coding standard violations. Any pointers on this ?

Answer (score 1):

> stop developers from checking-in their code into ClearCase in-case of any coding standard violations

That means locking.
Either locking the UCM stream (if you are using ClearCase UCM) or locking the branch which is monitored by your Hudson.
See [`cleartool lock`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm).

The idea is to prevent anyone to checkout/checking (except the account used by the Hudson if it needs to modify any file)

---

On the "failed build" part, a plugin like [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) might help (a Jenkins one, but it could be ported for Hudson too)

Comment: thanks for your response. We are using BaseClearCase. Our Hudson currently is not live monitoring the ClearCase SCM for any checkout/checkin changes. Hudson is just configured with a Job to run daily on a specified time.  <br><br> prevent anyone to checkout/checking  <br>  I thought we should be putting a ClearCase trigger to achieve this. Could you please clarify where & how to apply your solution (i.e. preventing anyone checking-in/out)

Comment: @yathirigan no trigger necessary (ie ClearCase doesn't need to take action on some external tool condition: the external tool needs to tell ClearCase what to do and when). Your job must use a view configured on a branch in order to get the sources it needs: if its fails, lock that branch. However, to add that extra step, the plugin I mention can help.

Comment: since our ClearCase instance is a "Base ClearCase" and not a UCM, we would not be having any branches. In that case, should i lock the code folder in the VOB ?

Comment: so what i understand is, a Job in Hudson will be monitoring the Code folder in my VOB for any check-in operation. And this job has to be configured to run when the check-in is triggered. This job will get the source codes from ClearCase, run a PMD check and if it goes beyond threshold, we need to lock the vob/folder in it. Could you please clarify if my understanding is correct ?

Comment: @yathirigan base ClearCase equals branch,  UCM equals Stream associated to branches. If your Hudson is monitoring a folder within a VOB, that involves a (base ClearCase)  view, from which you can extract a config spec (cleartool catcs), which will display the branch used here.  (probably master).  That's the branch you will want to lock in case of a failed build.